# Mobile friendly price slider

Tags: e-commerce, range, price-range, widget

I want to design a range filter for an ecommerce platform that has excellent UX for mobile users.

Here's the basic interaction I could make

[image]

1) Where do I put the current range (when slider is not moving) ?

- Option 1: Static in the center. This leads to unnecessary white-space

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOoJuI.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

- Option 2: Above each of the handles. This may get covered by the users thumb.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3i4gJ.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with the sliders shown in your question, I will suggest you go with **Option 2**

Additionally, I guess this will work perfectly on mobiles as the track sliders would be a little difficult for precision with fingers.

[image]

This page has some more options and the code too http://www.jqueryrain.com/?ot4e1H_o

Comment: Wow! This is unique. But it will be harder to code and requires a lot more space :(

Comment: @user3210476 you can keep it small and the code is already available on the website.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not using JQuery in our current project, and the implementation would have to be coded in React.

Comment: The link appears to be dead...

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 since in that instance the value is clearly mapped to the handle.

And I don't think you need to worry about the value being covered by the finger or thumb. In the scenario of setting the range the interaction is totally focused to this task, which means that you can let the value take up quite a generous bit of space, meaning it can be displayed above the finger. Once the user release the handle the value can shrink to fit other elements in the layout.